# Update Javascript Timer Interval periodically

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am creating a javascript function to show the status of a running task [ which will run in every 1 hour and it took  some time for completion]
This function will give an idea to end user that the task is currently running or not

To do this on load event i created a function and set an interval of 10 minutes to that So every 10 minutes it will tell user the status of task

In case if task is found as running on server i would like to reduce the interval to 1 minute . SO as soon as task is finished users will get an idea and they can restart using the web portal.
And once its detected as not running would like to revert the interval back to old 10 minute again.

Current implementation is like below

```
       $(function () {           
            loadSyncStatus();
            setInterval(function () {
                // Invoke function every 10 minutes (600000)
                loadSyncStatus();
            }, 600000);
        
        });
    
    function loadSyncStatus() {
        var action_url = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/GetSyncStatus")';             
        $.ajax({
            url: action_url,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {                    
                   $("#dataSyncStatus").html(response.message);
                   
                    if(response.running_flag=true){
                      //check the status every 1 minute *****TODO****
                    }
                    else{
                     //reset the interval back to 10 minutes  *****TODO****
                    }                       
                }
        }) 
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible to change the delay of a running interval, you've to clear the original interval, and start a new interval with a new delay value.

Comment: The first issue is that you throw away what `setInterval()` returns. That would be the ID which you can use to shut down the timer. In its current form it runs forever, hard to imagine how you were satisfied with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clearInterval` based on ids:

```js
let id = setInterval(function () {
 // Invoke function every 10 minutes (600000)
  loadSyncStatus();
}, 600000);
```

and

```js
if(response.running_flag=true){
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(loadSyncStatus, 60000);
}
else{
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(loadSyncStatus, 600000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this
it will call `loadSyncStatus()` after `600000`

```
var myTimeOut=0;
    $(function () {     
            loadSyncStatus();
         myTimeOut = setTimeout(loadSyncStatus, 600000);
        });

function loadSyncStatus() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    myTimeOut = setTimeout(loadSyncStatus, 600000);
    var action_url = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/GetSyncStatus")';             
    $.ajax({
        url: action_url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {                    
               $("#dataSyncStatus").html(response.message);
               
                if(response.running_flag=true){
                  //check the status every 1 minute *****TODO****
                }
                else{
                 //reset the interval back to 10 minutes  *****TODO****
                }                       
            }
    }) 
}
```